# Am I able to do: import java.*?

Tags: java, import

I was curious if I would be able to just do: import java.* when using java, and have almost everything I would need imported. Is this possible? I do not need to do this, the question just crossed my mind and I was curious.
Thanks!

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: It might took longer to compile your code.isn't it?

Comment: You would still need fully qualified names for `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` and such alike.

Comment: There is a reason namespaces exist - even if this worked how you imagined it working, it would still cause huge problems as there are often classes and packages with the same name, which would then conflict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`import something.*` isn't recursive. You'd only get all the classes in the specified package, not the sub-packages.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Since there are no classes in the `java` root package, `import java.*;` won't do anything.

Comment: There is no such concept as "sub-packages". Different packages have no relations at all.

Comment: You are correct strictly speaking, however 'sub-package' is a commonly used term that even Sun/Oracle use.

Comment: A commonly misleading term... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense because there is no class in java.* package.

Answer (score 0):

Packages in java are **not** hierarchical, even though the file system is. A package name is simply a namespace. `java.lang.reflect` is not related to `java.lang` at all. Both are totally different names.

The only hierarchical aspect is that a namespace can mapped to a folder structure and that this convention is used by the most common classloader, that would expect classes from packace `com.example.util` in the folder `./com/example/util`. But that's all.